# Mining in geth 1.5.9 doens't work ubuntu 14.0

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

When I execute `miner.start(1)` in the geth console I get

```
I0503 10:43:45.019183 miner/worker.go:517] commit new work on block 29 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 323.985µs and still stopped there without mining.
```

The difficulty isn't too high of the padding block (132480).
I am using  geth 1.5.9 on ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone help me please

Comment: What does `eth.hashrate` print? What does `eth.getBlock('latest')` say about the difficulty?

Comment: eth.hashrate prints 6 and `eth.getBlock('latest')
{
  difficulty: 132544,
...
  totalDifficulty: 3821696,

}`

Comment: Could you try running with Geth 1.6.0? We've reworked some things and I trust those logs and hashrate reporting better tbh.

Comment: I can 't remove to geth 1.6.0 because I started myproject with 1.5.9!